# How to correctly use a LC meter/bridge

Tags: inductor, measurement, bridge

I have a LC meter at hand that I'd like to use it to measure the inductance (dominated by L1) of a circuit branch like this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9hNa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bridge I'm using has the following settings:

- Frequency: 100Hz or 1kHz
- Assumption: parallel or series
- Bias ON/OFF: I don't know what that one does, when activated the unit freezes and the screen shows "Bias"...
- Q ON/OFF: Certainly to display the quality factor instead of the value of inductance/capacitance

First, in my case R1 is much lower so I intend to use the series assumption, but in the general case where R2 is the same order of magnitude of R1, what should be used: parallel, or series?

Second, the inductance is supposed to be independent on the frequency, so what's the effect that forces us to test at particular frequencies?

Edit: On request, here are the results of a quick test I've just run:

> Series, 100Hz: 18.8mH
>
> Series, 1kHz: 18.3mH
>
> Parallel, 100Hz: **1.4H**
>
> Parallel, 1kHz: **33mH**

Please note that I have a LED in series with R2 and a diode "head to toe" across that LED (to protect it against negative voltages), which will certainly change the "seen" resistance of R2. In this particular test case, R1=96Ohms and R2 = 1.5kOhms.

Comment: Why not do the measurements on all the ranges and if you can't make sense of something report the numbers back here?

Comment: Parallel capacitance (eg. as you approach the SRF) will affect the reading at high frequencies. At low frequencies you may not have enough signal to get a good reading if the inductance is very low. If XL is 1m\$\Omega\$ at the test frequency, you're obviously not going to have much voltage, no? You should be comparing R1 to XL and R2 to XL **at the test frequency**.

Comment: @AndyAka: Updated my question with test results.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: very true, thanks. Care to expand in a bit more details how that fits in the measurement method?

Comment: What was R1 and R2 do you think?

Comment: The question is intended to be rather general, but I've updated the post with the values of R1 and R2. Let's call this an illustration case.

Comment: Why adding external resistors? You can think of the inductor as already having a resistance due to the coil's wire and a resistance to take into account the core losses.

Comment: Because sometimes we need more resistance than what the inductor has internally? In this particular case, I need to dissipate a certain amount of power.

Comment: Do you mean that the LCR meter would damage this inductor if put alone?

Comment: I just understood what you meant with your previous post. I mean that I only have access to that black box, can't take the inductor out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An LC meter basically measures impedance at a given frequency as shown in the diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSgAni.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've calculated that your inductor is around 21.3 mH, its reactance is therefore \$X=2\pi·100·21.3m \Omega\$ . If you look at the impedance of your whole circuit at 100 Hz, it becomes: $$\frac{(R1+jX)·R2} {R1+R2+jX}=90.32+j·11.82$$.

If LC meter is operated at series mode at 100 Hz, it sees \$L1=\frac {11.82} {2\pi·100}=18.8 mH\$.

Let's now calculate the admittance of this impedance: $$Y=\frac {1} {90.32+j·11.82}=0.0109-j·0.0014$$

The admittance of the parallel circuit (at the right of the image) is given by $$1/R2-j1/X$$ where X is the reactance of L2. Therefore, when LC meter is operated in parallel mode, it will find \$X=1/0.0014=714.3 \Omega\$. Therefore \$L2=714.3/(2\pi·100)=1.14 H\$.

The important point is that your original circuit is equivalent to the circuits in the images **only** at the given frequency. And that the LC meter is either finding L1 or L2, depending on the selected mode.

If you repeat the calculations for f=1000 Hz, you'll find: L1=18.7 mH (series) and L2=32.5 mH (parallel). All those values are rather close to your LC meter readings. The difference might be attribuable to the presence of the LED and other factors not being taken into account.

Added: I'll explicitly answer to your questions now:

> First, in my case R1 is much lower so I intend to use the series
>   assumption, but in the general case where R2 is the same order of
>   magnitude of R1, what should be used: parallel, or series?

If the impedance you're testing doesn't fit a series neither a parallel model. Then the inductance value given by the LCR meter, in both modes, will be far away from the "embedded" inductance value and highly dependent on the test frequency.

You can therefore use any of the modes and, by circuit analysis, calculate what is the value of the "embedded" inductor. This is what I did to get the 21.3 mH value above. I looked at the imaginary part of \$\frac{(R1+jX)·R2} {R1+R2+jX}\$ and solved the unknown X that would make it equal to the reactance of 18.8 mH (as per your LCR readings).

> Second, the inductance is supposed to be independent on the frequency,
>   so what's the effect that forces us to test at particular frequencies?

As seen before, unless you're testing an inductor that perfectly fits one of the models (series or parallel), the reading will depend on the frequency. Even if you're testing an inductor that perfectly fits the model, your LCR meter might have different accuracy depending on the range **and** the test frequency. The datasheet will give the accuracy numbers for different ranges and test frequencies.

It is also worth noting that some parameters, like the core losses of an inductor, depends on the frequency. The losses are related to the inductor quality factor Q. Finally, at higher frequency, you might approach the self resonance of the inductor, in which case the L reading will be substantially different to the L seen at low frequency.

Comment: Excellent answer, kudos.